# Global onException and interceptor definitions outside Camel context?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have multiple Camel applications (written in Spring DSL) and they all share the same onException and a number of interceptors defined globally in the camel context. I'm wondering if it's possible to have onException and interceptors defined in a separate XML file somewhere in the class path and include or inject it into camel context when the app starts. Java DSL has `adviceWith`, but is there such thin in Spring DSL as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently. However in Camel 3.12 onwards we are adding such feature which is called *route configuration*

You can read about it here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/route-configuration.html

Comment: Claus, this is exactly what I need! I assume it will be possible to configure this on the camel context level, e.g. `<camelContext routeConfigurationId="xmlError">`, correct?

Comment: Hello Claus, sorry to bother you, but I'm trying to get some clarity on how to use the route configurations. My impression was that route configurations can be defined in separate XML files and injected into the context, but based on what I see in the Camel code, they can be only defined inside Camel contexts - is this correct? If yes, is it possible to submit an enhancement request? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981931/cannot-locate-beandefinitionparser-for-element-routeconfigurations

Comment: XML files can be loaded, but you need camel on spring boot or standalone camel for this. The old <camelContext> XML with legacy Spring / Blueprint is limited.

Comment: I created a ticket for the old spring-xml: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17272

Comment: Camel 3.14 will support classic/old Spring XML where you can use <routeConfigurationContext> in other XML files that you can refer to from <camelContext> - similar to how you can do with routes.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary "solution" was to store the route configuration XML files in some pre-defined location, e.g. "/routeConfigurations" and I added the following code to my SpringBoot application class:

```
    @Bean
    public void initRouteConfigurations() throws Exception {
        SpringCamelContext springCamelContext = (SpringCamelContext) camelContext;

        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] routeConfigurations = resolver.getResources("/routeConfigurations/*");

        for (Resource r : routeConfigurations) {
            InputStream is = r.getURL().openStream();
            ModelParser parser = new ModelParser(is, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring");
            Optional<RouteConfigurationsDefinition> definitionsOptional = parser.parseRouteConfigurationsDefinition();
            RouteConfigurationsDefinition routeConfigurationsDefinition = definitionsOptional.get();
            springCamelContext.addRouteConfigurations(routeConfigurationsDefinition.getRouteConfigurations());
        }
    }
```